# How to handle Invalid XML String and Invalid JSON String in Dataframe / Spark SQL/ Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a scenario, where I have to parse the XML and JSON values based on another field.

`Customer_Order` table have two fields named `response_id` and `response_output`. `response_output` will have a combination of JSON strings, XML Strings, Error, Blanks, and Nulls.

I need to address below Problem Statements

***problem statements***

- If response_id=1 and response_output have valid JSON then pick JSON
  logic
- If response_id=1 and response_output is not have valid JSON then
  Nullify
- If response_id=1 and response_output is XML value then Nullify
- If response_id=1 and response_output is Error then Error
- If response_id=1 and response_output is Blank or Null then Nullify
- If response_id=2 and response_output have valid JSON then pick XML
  logic
- If response_id=2 and response_output is not have valid XML then
  Nullify
- If response_id=2 and response_output is JSON value then Nullify
- If response_id=2 and response_output is Error then Error
- If response_id=2 and response_output is Blank or Null then Nullify

when I am trying to achieve the above problem statements using SPARK SQL but my code is breaking when I am encountering invalid XML or invalid JSON.

Below is the error and Could anyone help me to handle this?

```
   spark.sql("""select 
    customer_id,
    response_id,
    CASE WHEN (response_id=2 and response_output!="Error") THEN get_json_object(response_output, '$.Metrics.OrderResponseTime')
         WHEN (response_id=1 and response_output!="Error") THEN xpath_string(response_output,'USR_ORD/OrderResponse/USR1OrderTotalTime')
         WHEN ((response_id=1 or response_id=2) and  response_output="Error") THEN "Error"
         ELSE null END as order_time 
         from Customer_Order""").show()
```

**Below Error I am Getting when trying the above query, How to handle invalid XML or JSON**

```
Driver stacktrace:
21/02/05 00:48:06 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 5 failed: show at Engine.scala:221, took 1.099890 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 83, srwredf2021.analytics1.test.dev.corp, executor 3): java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid XML document: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1234; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
<USR_ORD><OrderResult><ORDTime>2021-02-02 10:34:19</ORDTime><ORDStatus>COMPLETE</ORDStatus><ORDValue><USR1OrderTotalTime>321</USR1OrderTotalTime><USR1OrderKYC>{ND}</USR1OrderKYC><USR1OrderLoc>{ND}</USR1OrderLoc><USR1Orderqnt>10</USR1Orderqnt><USR1Orderxyz>0</USR1Orderxyz><USR1OrderD>{ND}</USR1OrderD></ORDValue></OrderResult><OrderResponse></USR_ORD>
```

***My Code snippets with data for reference***

**Data List**

```
    val custList = List((100,1,"<USR_ORD><OrderResult><ORDTime>2021-02-02 10:34:19</ORDTime><ORDStatus>COMPLETE</ORDStatus><ORDValue><USR1OrderTotalTime>321</USR1OrderTotalTime><USR1OrderKYC>{ND}</USR1OrderKYC><USR1OrderLoc>{ND}</USR1OrderLoc><USR1Orderqnt>10</USR1Orderqnt><USR1Orderxyz>0</USR1Orderxyz><USR1OrderD>{ND}</USR1OrderD></ORDValue></OrderResult><OrderResponse></USR_ORD>"),
(200,1,"<USR_ORD><OrderResponse><OrderResult><ORDTime>2021-02-02 21:13:12</ORDTime><ORDStatus>COMPLETE</ORDStatus><ORDValue><USR1OrderTotalTime>221</USR1OrderTotalTime><USR1OrderKYC>{ND}</USR1OrderKYC><USR1OrderLoc>{ND}</USR1OrderLoc><USR1Orderqnt>10</USR1Orderqnt><USR1Orderxyz>0</USR1Orderxyz><USR1OrderD>{ND}</USR1OrderD></ORDValue></OrderResult></OrderResponse></USR_ORD>"),
(300,1,"Error"),
(400,1,""),
(500,1,"""{"OrderResponseTime":"2021-02-02 11:34:19", "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":300, "USR1Order":null, "USR1Orderqut":10 }"""),
(600,2,"""{"OrderResponseTime":"2021-02-02 15:14:13", "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":300, "USR1Order":null, "USR1Orderqut":10 }"""),
(700,2,"""{"OrderResponseTime":"2021-02-02 12:38:26", "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":200, "USR1Order":null "USR1Orderqut":4} """),
(800,2,"""{"OrderResponseTime":"2021-02-02 13:24:19", "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":100, "USR1Order":null} "USR1Orderqut":1}"""),
(900,2,"<USR_ORD><OrderResponse><OrderResult><ORDTime>2021-02-02 01:12:49</ORDTime><ORDStatus>COMPLETE</ORDStatus><ORDValue><USR1OrderTotalTime>221</USR1OrderTotalTime><USR1OrderKYC>{ND}</USR1OrderKYC><USR1OrderLoc>{ND}</USR1OrderLoc><USR1Orderqnt>10</USR1Orderqnt><USR1Orderxyz>0</USR1Orderxyz><USR1OrderD>{ND}</USR1OrderD></ORDValue></OrderResult></OrderResponse></USR_ORD>"),
(101,2,"Error"),
(202,2,""));
```

**Loading List to RDD**

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(custList)
```

**Imposing Schema Column Names**

```
val DF1 = rdd.toDF("customer_id","response_id","response_output")
```

**Creating Table**

```
DF1.createOrReplaceTempView("Customer_Order")
```

**Printing Schema**

```
spark.sql("""select customer_id,response_id,response_output from Customer_Order""").printSchema()

root
 |-- customer_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- response_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- response_output: string (nullable = true)
```

**Showing Records**

```
spark.sql("""select customer_id,response_id,response_output from Customer_Order""").show()

+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|customer_id|response_id|response_output                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|100        |1          |<USR_ORD><OrderResult><ORDStatus>COMPLETE</ORDStatus><ORDValue><USR1OrderTotalTime>321</USR1OrderTotalTime><USR1OrderKYC>{ND}</USR1OrderKYC><USR1OrderLoc>{ND}</USR1OrderLoc><USR1Orderqnt>10</USR1Orderqnt><USR1Orderxyz>0</USR1Orderxyz><USR1OrderD>{ND}</USR1OrderD></ORDValue></OrderResult><OrderResponse></USR_ORD>                |
|200        |1          |<USR_ORD><OrderResponse><OrderResult><ORDStatus>COMPLETE</ORDStatus><ORDValue><USR1OrderTotalTime>221</USR1OrderTotalTime><USR1OrderKYC>{ND}</USR1OrderKYC><USR1OrderLoc>{ND}</USR1OrderLoc><USR1Orderqnt>10</USR1Orderqnt><USR1Orderxyz>0</USR1Orderxyz><USR1OrderD>{ND}</USR1OrderD></ORDValue></OrderResult></OrderResponse></USR_ORD>|
|300        |1          |Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
|400        |1          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
|500        |1          |{ "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":300, "USR1Order":null, "USR1Orderqut":10 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|600        |2          |{ "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":300, "USR1Order":null, "USR1Orderqut":10 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
|700        |2          |{ "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":200, "USR1Order":null "USR1Orderqut":4}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
|800        |2          |{ "OrderResponse":"COMPLETE", "OrderTime":100, "USR1Order":null} "USR1Orderqut":1}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
|900        |2          |<USR_ORD><OrderResponse><OrderResult><ORDStatus>COMPLETE</ORDStatus><ORDValue><USR1OrderTotalTime>221</USR1OrderTotalTime><USR1OrderKYC>{ND}</USR1OrderKYC><USR1OrderLoc>{ND}</USR1OrderLoc><USR1Orderqnt>10</USR1Orderqnt><USR1Orderxyz>0</USR1Orderxyz><USR1OrderD>{ND}</USR1OrderD></ORDValue></OrderResult></OrderResponse></USR_ORD>|
|101        |2          |Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
|202        |2          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JSON you don't need to validate it as `get_json_object` will not fail if the path doesn't exist or the json is not valid.

To avoid exception when extracting values from XML, you can use UDF function to check whether the string `response_output` can be parsed to XML or not :

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

val isParsableXML = (xml: String) => {
  Try(scala.xml.XML.loadString(xml)) match {
    case Success(_) => true
    case Failure(_) => false
  }
}

spark.udf.register("is_parsable_xml", isParsableXML)
```

Then using it in your SQL query :

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT customer_id,
       response_id,
       CASE
           WHEN (response_id=2
                 AND response_output!='Error') THEN get_json_object(response_output, '$.OrderTime')
           WHEN (response_id=1
                 AND response_output!='Error'
                 AND is_parsable_xml(response_output)) THEN xpath_string(response_output, 'USR_ORD/OrderResponse/USR1OrderTotalTime')
           WHEN ((response_id=1
                  OR response_id=2)
                 AND response_output='Error') THEN 'Error'
           ELSE NULL
       END AS order_time
FROM Customer_Order 
""").show()

//+-----------+-----------+----------+
//|customer_id|response_id|order_time|
//+-----------+-----------+----------+
//|        100|          1|      null|
//|        200|          1|          |
//|        300|          1|     Error|
//|        400|          1|      null|
//|        500|          1|      null|
//|        600|          2|       300|
//|        700|          2|      null|
//|        800|          2|       100|
//|        900|          2|      null|
//|        101|          2|     Error|
//|        202|          2|      null|
//+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Now you can write your case when logic.